# Divisibility of factorial and Legendre's theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to show that for $n \in \mathbb{N}$:
$$n!(n-1)!\mid(2n-2)!$$
I think the proof uses *Legendre's Theorem*:

> *Theorem*: Let $f(p,n!)$ denote the highest power of $p$ dividing $n!$, then $$f(p,n!)= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^k}\right\rfloor$$

So I want to show that 
$$f(p,(2n-2)!)-f(p,n!)-f(p,(n-1)!)>0$$
but I dont' know how to proceed, please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $$\binom {2n-2}{n-1}-\binom {2n-2}{n-2}=\frac {(2n-2)!}{n!(n-1)!}$$